# Laravel API calls failing in Production

Tags: vuejs2, apache2, laravel-6, php-7.4

I'm currently working on a **VueJS+Laravel 6** project.

Everything is working ok in Localhost, but in Production, **although the web routes work well, the API calls fail.**

I have **no errors in the Apache log and Laravel log.**

Am I missing anything that I should update related to Laravel passport?

I simly run `php artisan passport:install` in production.

This is what I install in the **Ubuntu server**

```
apt-get install zip unzip fail2ban python php7.4-common php7.4-cli php7.4-gd php7.4-mysql php7.4-curl php7.4-intl php7.4-mbstring php7.4-bcmath php7.4-imap php7.4-xml php7.4-zip apache2 libapache2-mod-php mysql-server ffmpeg cron npm nodejs
```

*I tried not to install fail2ban, but it didn't help.*

This is my virtualhost

```
    <VirtualHost *:80 *:443>

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/public

            <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride None
            </Directory>
            <Directory /var/www/myproject>
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

I set up the following rights:

```
chown -R www-data.www-data ./ && chmod -R 755 ./ && chmod -R 777 storage && chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache/
```

And these are the artisan commands I run

```
php artisan key:generate && php artisan migrate:fresh --seed && php artisan storage:link && php artisan passport:install && php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... I was apparently missing to run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Leaving it here for a case it helps someone else in the future